# Doctrine MongoDB query embedded documents

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-orm

I have top-level document User with embedded Keyword documents (User EmbedMany Keyword).
Well i don't know how to get Keyword object from concrete User by Keyword's id
I spent a lot of time trying to solve this but it still open problem for me.
So i help someone here will help me.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load only parent document from the mongodb. But there is [$slice](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields) operator that can load   parent document just with limited number of embedded documents.

On native mongodb language you can do it so:

```
db.users.find({_id: "UserId", "Keywords._id", "keywordId"},
               {Keywords:{$slice: 1}}) // first matched by id keyword
```

From doctrine you will receive user document with only one embedded keyword.

Hope this helps.